# Using Eclipse ant plugin from command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, command-line, eclipse-plugin

I know this is not a smart question.

I need to use ant from command line and there is Ant plugin in Eclipse, so I have tried to specify ANT_HOME in Eclipse to be set to the directory of that plugin.

```
C:\Users\Nikolay>ant
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Should I install a separate Ant from [Apache](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html) to enable Ant from command line?

Comment: Yes, install Ant (and put it in your path).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the best solution is to install ant, but you can use the binaries that are from Eclipse too. You will find the binaries under `eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030`. Note that the plugin the version may be different on your machine. Something like:

`${eclipse_location}\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030\bin\ant`

should work. But this should be used only for solving something quick, until you can install ant. Since you will upgrade your Eclipse/plugins and the paths will change and you will need to keep updating your environment variables this way.

Comment: In Eclipse - Window - Preferences - Ant - Runtime - Ant Home this folder is selected. Then I type ant in command line ant it does not work.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov In order to work by typing just `ant` you need to include your ant bin directory in your `PATH`.

Comment: If we are talking about ant plugin directory then it does not have bin subfolder, only lib.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Hmm, in my `org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030` I have a bin too. I'm using Eclipse Indigo (3.7).

Comment: I am also using Eclipse Indigo. What are the files there in bin folder? I have tried to put lib folder in PATH but it does not work.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Under `bin` directory you should have the ant script file along with others like: antRun, ant.cmd, ant.bat, etc. `Lib` under PATH it will not have any meaning. Since under lib there are only the `jar` files. I suggest following my answer and install `ant` properly, if you have the authority. Else you should look in your Eclipse plugin directory if you are using the proper `org.apache.ant_...` dir as a ANT_HOME.

Comment: nb: "installing" can be cut short by copying the contents of `${eclipse_location}\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030` to a newly created 'c:\ant'. Put into path. Be done.